# nodes and structures in c

Tags: c, struct, nodes, huffman-code

I'm trying to make a huffman coder.. but I'm having some problems...

This is how I define my structure of a node..

```
struct node{

int type,prob;
char *code;
struct node *left, *right;
```

};

I order by probabilities and I create a new node

```
struct node join_nodes(struct node no1, struct node no2)
{
    struct node aux; 

    aux.type = 1; 
    aux.prob = no1.prob + no2.prob;
    aux.right = &no1; 
    aux.left = &no2;

    return aux;

}
```

Then I put this new node in the list of nodes..

```
   void sort_hufman(struct node order_list[], struct node list[])
{
        int i = N, len = N; 
        struct node aux;
        for(i=N; i>N-2;i--)
        {
                sort(order_list, i);
                len = len +1; 

                aux = join_nodes(order_list[i-1],order_list[i-2]);

                list[len-1] = order_list[i-2] = aux;

        }
}
```

The thing is that in this fuctions my first subnode types are 0 and 0 that this means that they are leafs but wen I chek in the code they change to type 1 and 0 ... I think that it is because (I don't know why the pointers of the subnodes points to same direction).. but it mustn't change..

where list and order list I've defined like *list and I've saved space in memory using malloc...

I don't know what it's happening...

can anyone help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two problems with your code: one serious, one in terms of naming.

---

In the function

```
struct node join_nodes(struct node no1, struct node no2)
```

`no1` and `no2` are passed by value. They are temporary objects, for all practical purposes. So the lines

```
aux.right = &no1; 
aux.left = &no2;
```

are problematic. You're pointing the pointers to objects that will soon die. Once the function exists, you cannot count on anything that's in them. They are just garbage objects.

Consider passing the objects by address, not by value:

```
struct node join_nodes(struct node *no1, struct node *no2)
{
Tnode_pointer aux = (Tnode_pointer)malloc(sizeof(Tnode));

    aux->type = 1; 
    aux->prob = no1->prob + no2->prob;
    aux->right = no1; 
    aux->left = no2;

    return aux;
}
```

and

```
aux = join_nodes(order_list[i-1],order_list[i-2]);
```

---

In

```
struct node{
...
int ...prob;
};
```

This is surely not a probability. You mean probably cardinality.

Comment: ohh thanks.. I thought that when I pass by value an argument his value don't change... 




but I didn't know that the value will disapear.. because you are pointing to directions of no1 and no2, not at variables you pass..



So I don't understand, when I make joint_nodes(list[1], list[2]) for example.. whats happening to misspoint to directions off list[1] and list[2]??

Comment: I know that actualy is not a probability, because it isn't a valu between 0 and 1.. is that you mean? 

Thaks again!

Comment: `aux->prob = no1->prob + no2->prob;` You changed them to pointer, remember?

Answer (score 0):

```
//I'm sorry I had to change the arguments to your function 

typedef struct node *Tnode_pointer;    
typedef struct node {
    int type,prob;
    char *code;
    Tnode_pointer left, right;
} Tnode;

Tnode_pointer join_nodes(Tnode *no1, Tnode *no2)
{
    Tnode_pointer aux = (Tnode_pointer)malloc(sizeof(Tnode));

    aux->type = 1; 
    aux->prob = no1->prob + no2->prob;
    aux->right = no1; 
    aux->left = no2;

    return aux;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
typedef struct node *Tnode_pointer;    
typedef struct node {
    int type,prob;
    char *code;
    Tnode_pointer left, right;
} Tnode;

Tnode_pointer join_nodes(Tnode no1, Tnode no2)
{
    Tnode_pointer aux = (Tnode_pointer)malloc(sizeof(Tnode));

    aux->type = 1; 
    aux->prob = no1.prob + no2.prob;
    aux->right = &no1; 
    aux->left = &no2;

    return aux;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you are taking addresses of temporaries. This is a serious bug.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was in a hurry actually :)
the argument of the function should be (Tnode *no1, Tnode *no2)

Comment: There's nothing to apologize. If you edit your answer, I'll be glad to remove the downvote.